# Await an array of Promises mapped from Object entries

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise, playwright

With the following snippet code the function should await all the promises mapped from the Object entries `node`. For instance the `$eval` function comes from the Playwright library and throws an error due to the fact that the target document in which the evaluate is performed will be closed by the time that the promises should be awaited.

The above error can be fixed by nesting another `await Promise.all` but I'm not getting why the external `await Promise.all` is not properly handling the inner loop given that I'm returning an array of `Promise`

```
const tableBodyRows = await page.locator(`tbody >> tr`).elementHandles()
      await Promise.all(
        tableData[pageIndex].map(async ({ node }, idx) => {
          // await Promise.all(
            return Object.entries(node).map(async ([key, val]) => {
              const cellText = await tableBodyRows[idx].$eval(
                `td.${key.toLowerCase()}`,
                (cell: HTMLTableCellElement) => cell.textContent,
              )
              return expect(cellText).toEqual(val)
            })
          // )
        }),
      )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others have said - you are returning an array of arrays.
If your target is es2019 or later - you can replace the map call, with flatMap

```
const tableBodyRows = await page.locator(`tbody >> tr`).elementHandles()
      await Promise.all(
        tableData[pageIndex].flatMap(({ node }, idx) =>
           Object.entries(node).map(async ([key, val]) => 
              expect(await tableBodyRows[idx].$eval(
                `td.${key.toLowerCase()}`,
                (cell: HTMLTableCellElement) => cell.textContent,
              )).toEqual(val)
           )
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Using `flatMap` doesn't work

Comment: That because I forget to remove the unneeded first async. Updated

Comment: Does adding the first async create a new level of Promises thus leading the outermost await to fail?

Comment: Yes - it was returning an array of promises, that each resolve to an array of promises.

Answer (score 2):

The result of your map is an array of arrays like this:

```
await Promise.all([[promise1, prmise2], [promise3, promise4]])
```

You need to flatten input of `Promise.all` first like this:

```
  await Promise.all(
    tableData[pageIndex].reduce(async (acc, { node }, idx) => {
      return [
        ...acc,
        ...Object.entries(node).map(async ([key, val]) => {
          const cellText = await tableBodyRows[idx].$eval(
            `td.${key.toLowerCase()}`,
            (cell: HTMLTableCellElement) => cell.textContent
          );
          return expect(cellText).toEqual(val);
        }),
      ];
    }, [])
  );
```

Comment: Yes, this should work. Another option to flatten the array is to stick [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) at the end: `tableData[pageIndex].map(async ({ node }, idx) {...}).flat()`

Comment: @RickN using `flat()` doesn't work

Comment: Ah, you're right, because it's a _function returning array elements_, rather than array themselves.

Comment: Because it's not flattening an array of arrays, but _trying_ to flatten an array of Promises. Since `tableData[pageIndex].map(async (...` doesn't actually do anything async itself, you could probably go with either flat/flatMap if you change it to `tableData[pageIndex].map((...`

Comment: So by getting rid of `async` for the outermost loop and using `flatMap` works, I'm not getting why

Comment: Does `async` create another level of promises?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `Promise.allSettled()` instead of inner `Promise.all()`